# is a domain necessary to https-encrypt my ec2 server?

Tags: security, encryption, amazon-ec2, mule, keystore

This question is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980763/mule-https-listener-wont-respond) stackoverflow question, on how to further secure my connection to the public.
My end goal is to have a react native app making request to my aws EC2 server. I obviously want the user login credentials to make a safe travel from the app to my server. For now im sending the credentials with http Authorization headers "basic username:password". This can be intercepted as i understand.

My AWS EC2 server can be reached with an elastic IP i've created. I'm using self signed certification which is not considerd "secure" by browsers. To get a secure certficiation i need to connect it with a domain, not an ip.

It seems illogical for me to expose my backend server to the public even more by getting a domain. I am fairly certain I've misunderstood the whole thing. All I want is to make safe requests to my server.

EDIT: My requests gets blocked, like the question i linked to, i need to approve the certification in the browser, after that i can access. I cant do this in every devide the app will be installed in.

Info about my backend:

```
AWS EC2 Micro
Windows Server 2016
Mulesoft 3.9.0CE listening to 0.0.0.0(all)
```

The keystore has a SAN included of my ec2:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore keystore.jks   -dname "CN=localhost, 
OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown"  -keypass password  
-storepass password  -keyalg RSA  -sigalg SHA1withRSA  -keysize 2048  -alias 
mule  -ext SAN=DNS:publicAWS-DNS,IP:elasticIP -validity 9999
```

Is my traffic already encrypted but just not considered "safe" by browsers? Is this ok?
Do i need to specify the IP with SANs when creating jks?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple levels of security you need to implement to secure you application.

- Encrypt the communication from browser client to the ec2 instance you need to use SSL Certificate Signed by a Certificate Authority (You can get free certificates from Amazon) to avoid man in the middle attacks.
- Implement authentication (Using Username and Passwords) for access control(Who can access your system).
- Implement authorization (Who can do what).

Note: To attach free SSL certificates issued by Amazon Certificate Authority you need to use a Application Load Balancer(ALB) where the certificate attached to the ALB and then connect the ALB to the EC2 instance.

> Is domain necessary for the backend?

It necessary though its not mandatory, since if you use a self-signed certificate for the IP address of the EC2 instance, browsers will request to proceed with caution.

Comment: As stated in the question, theese certifications requires a domain. Do i really need to give my backend a domain?

Comment: Its necessary though its not mandatory. Check the updated answer

Comment: alright, so my fetchs and posts through react native should be valid. Thank you!

Comment: My requests gets blocked, like the question i linked to, i need to approve the certification in the browser, after that i can access. I cant do this in every devide the app will be installed in.